# Add days to selected days in holidays and more Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, math, input, calendar

Dear StackOverFlow users,
I'm currently making an 'calendar' with date input for an apartman.
I have never doing this, or similar before so i need to get help.
I got 2 criterion which the calendar need to do:

1. You can only arrive in 3 days from today ( So if its 2023.10.12 you can select only 2023.10.15 in check in date input )
2. the minimum booking days is 2, so if you selected 2023.10.15 you can only click to 2023.10.17
   in check out date input
3. In specific days (like: last day of the year,memoral day) the minimum booking is 3 days (so if i selected 2023.12.24 i can only check out in 2023.12.27 )

Im making this calendar, here is the JS and HTML

```
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="checking">Check In</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="checkin" id="inputdate" >
                      </div>
                     </div>
                    <div class="col">
                     <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <label for="checkout">Check Out</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="checkout"  id="inputdate2">
                      </div>
                     </div>
```

```
                        <script>
                        // checkin
                        $(function(){
                            var dtToday = new Date();
                         
                            var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
                            var day = dtToday.getDate() + 3;// aznap + 3 nap 
                            var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
                            if(month < 10)
                                month = '0' + month.toString();
                            if(day < 10)
                                day = '0' + day.toString();
                            
                            var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                            
                            $('#inputdate').attr('min', maxDate);
                        });
                                //check out             
                        $(function(){
                            var dtToday = new Date();
                         
                            var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
                            var day = dtToday.getDate()+5; //
                            var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
                            if(month < 10)
                                month = '0' + month.toString();
                            if(day < 10)
                                day = '0' + day.toString();
                            
                            var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                            
                            $('#inputdate2').attr('min', maxDate);
                        });
                        </script>
```